# Setup ssh server on a headless Ubuntu server with a removable boot disk

Tags: command-line, networking, software-installation, ssh, files

I have a computer with an industrial control type motherboard with no video output ports or video cards.

Ubuntu 18.04 server OS boots from a Compact-Flash drive. I installed the OS via cloning.

I would like to add an ssh server to the OS, by adding it to the disk.

The ssh-server was not installed at the time of server OS installation.

How do I add an ssh-server to a bootable hard drive?

Comment: Maybe, the boot disk a a compact flash, for an industrial control type motherboard. 
I could clone it to a hard drive, boot it, install ssh, and clone it back to the flash. That seems pretty convoluted. I could try to boot via usb card reader, that might  work. 
A third option: I use a micro controler to give shell commands, emulating a keyboard to install and set up ssh-server.  All of those seem like overly complex. 
I was thinking if I could just add some files for ssh server, and tell it to run on boot that would be simpler.

Comment: Does my answr solve your problem?

Comment: I am deleting my answer as it does not help with your problem.